# Dúvida sobre a questão "Agência Bancária" da OBI 2012

Tags: python

Estou com uma dúvida em como resolver esse problema:

Entrada:

> A primeira linha da entrada contém dois inteiros separados por um espaço em branco. O primeiro, C, é o número de caixas ativas na agência bancária. O segundo, N, o número de clientes que procurarão atendimento na agência naquele dia. As próximas N linhas terão cada uma informações sobre um cliente, consistindo de dois inteiros, T e D, separados por um espaço em branco. O inteiro T fornece o momento em que o cliente entra na fila, em minutos, a partir do instante de abertura da agência. O inteiro D fornece, em minutos, o tempo necessário para atender o cliente. As linhas estão ordenadas por entrada dos clientes na fila.

Saída:

> A saída deverá conter apenas uma linha, contendo um único inteiro, o número de clientes cujo atendimento será iniciado mais do que 20 minutos após sua entrada na fila.

A entrada que ele dá é a seguinte:

> 1 5 - 0 10 - 0 10 - 1 10 - 2 10 - 30 10

Sendo o 1 o total de caixas ativos, 5 o total de clientes, e o demais a hora de chegada do cliente e o tempo que ele vai levar pra ser atendido respectivamente.

E a saída nesse caso é 1.

Outro exemplo:

> 3 16 - 0 10 - 0 10 - 0 10 - 3 10 - 5 10 - 7 10- 11 10 - 13 10- 14 10 - 15 10 - 16 10 - 17 10 - 18 3 - 19 10 - 20 10 - 23 3

Seguindo a mesma lógica já explicada anteriormente.

A saída para essa entrada é para ser 2.

Eu não estou conseguindo desenvolver um algoritmo/código para esse problema, alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Importante [editar sua pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/580891/70) (restaurando-a se necessário), trocando o código apresentado por um [mcve] do problema, e uma explicação do que tentou e qual foi a dificuldade em resolver. Para entender o propósito deste site consulte a [help] e respectivos links. Para evitar descentralização de informações o campo de comentários desta postagem foi desativado, mas o da pergunta original continua funcional.